# Update Docker image when there are no changes to Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

Let's say I created a docker image using a command like

`docker build -t myimage .`

In the current directory where I built the image, I have

`ls`

Dockerfile
myscript.py

Later, I made changes to ONLY the "myscript.py" file. How do I update the image without needing to rebuild?

Comment: The way you update an image is by rebuilding the image. If there is a particular problem you're trying to solve you might want to update your question with your complete Dockerfile; there are ways of structuring your Dockerfile for Python projects to minimize the amount of work that needs to be done when updating source files (e.g., by installing dependencies seperately from your Python sources).

Comment: Updating files can be done on a container and not on an image by using `volume`. Auto update the image there's no other way but to rebuild the image since your Dockerfile will need to run again the line which copies your files into the image.